# Split database used by two projects

Tags: mysql, database, system-administration

In my new work, they have two php projects(project A, project B). Both projects are using the same MYSQL Database. Each project has a different developing team and end users. And each project has its own tables, and there are a common tables which both projects reads/writes data, and sometimes they use this common tables to send information from project A to project B, so project B depend on data inserted by project A ,and the problem here is the database schema has a dirty structure and conception and now the team A are redeveloping the project A from scratch and we want to work with other clean schema structure

In the other hand my (draft) opinion is to split the database into two databases, one for each project, and each time insert, update, delete the common data in the two databases

or develop external code to copy the last updated data from database A to B every X period

I want to know your opinion on this topic

Comment: There's nothing wrong with two applications sharing a database if there's data that actually is needed in both. On the contrary that's rather ideally, having them each have their own database would require some cumbersome synchronization mechanism and is error prone. Splitting the database causes redundancies which should be a big no-no. Sharing the database also allows for easy queries over the whole data, let's say for the bosses who aren't interested in the details of each application but rather want reports about "the big picture".

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't really be ideal to run sql queries in multiple databases, the code can get messy.

The ideal way to go about it would be to keep one database and just clean it up so the structure is more acceptable.

But if you are fine with running queries in multiple databases for each action, you can split them into two.